# I am getting this error while running react-native app in android studio

Tags: android, react-native, build

Here i shared the error.

Caused by: java.lang.Exception: Command `config` unrecognized. Make sure that you have run `npm install` and that you are inside a react-native project.

Comment: Make sure you have packages of npm installed in your projects dir

Comment: I installed all the packages

Answer (score 0):

You can temporarily bypass the issue by forcing the @react-native-community/cli-platform-android to use the older version 3.0.2.

```
npm install --save @react-native-community/cli-platform-android@3.0.2
```

OR

```
yarn add @react-native-community/cli-platform-android@3.0.2
```